# How do I make fuseki serve gzipped content?

Tags: gzip, jena, fuseki

I started a fuseki sever with the command:

```
./fuseki-server --gzip=yes --update --loc=DB /dataset
```

Then, after posting some data, I tried to download the gzipped content with the command:

```
curl -X GET \
    -H "Accept: application/x-gzip" \
    -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" \
    http://localhost:3030/dataset
```

But the content was not gzipped. Do I need additional headers/configuration to make gzipping work?

Comment: Or you could stick an Apache web server in front and mod_proxy_http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standalone Fuseki 2.4.0 does not support gzip encoding in the standalone server. The feature seems to have got lost at some time.

Recorded as:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-1200

You can set it if you use the Fuseki WAR file by configuring Apache Tomcat or Eclipse Jetty or other webapp container server.

Comment: can you direct me to a Fuseki + gzip configuration for Jetty or tomcat that I could use as an example?

Comment: When run as a war file, the jetty or tomcat setup is provided purely by jetty or tomcat - there isn't anything special for Fuseki here.  See the documentation of either system.

Comment: Some changes have been pushed to the development master to address JENA-1200.  The next development build (tomorrow or so - not a formal release) will pick them up.